# Blank String Causing Unexpected Output in Data Removal

Tags: python, list

I have encountered an error in attempting to clean data from a list.

**This Code:**

```
priceList = ['$301,000', '','3 days', '$33,333', '', '2 days', '$40,000', '6 days']

for i in priceList:
    if not "$" in i:
        priceList.remove(i)
```

**Returns this output:**

```
['$301,000', '3 days', '$33,333', '2 days', '$40,000']
```

**Instead of this**:

```
['$301,000', '$33,333', '$40,000']
```

Note the blank strings ( ' ' ) in the original list. Though these are removed as expected, the proceeding 'days' values are consequently skipped (*the only days value ('6 Days') removed as expected does not have a preceding blank string.*)

I have tried various methods to no avail.

Comment: The problem is you are modifying a list while trying to iterate over it.   After you delete items, the `for` loop pointer is wrong.   Instead, build a new list that has the items you want to keep.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> priceList = ['$301,000', '','3 days', '$33,333', '', '2 days', '$40,000', '6 days']
>>> priceList = [price for price in priceList if '$' in price]
>>> priceList
['$301,000', '$33,333', '$40,000']
```

or use filter by passing a lambda function to check if that symbol is present on elements

```py
>>> list(filter(lambda x: '$' in x, priceList))
['$301,000', '$33,333', '$40,000']

# also is equivalent to define foo
def foo(x):
    return '$' in x
#...
>>> list(filter(foo, priceList))
['$301,000', '$33,333', '$40,000']
```